# The dropdown in the mat-autocomplete is moving when i move the modal window

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is a sample code of material modal window HTML.
When I drag the modal about, if I have the dropdown suggestion open, it however does not move with the window. How can this be solved?

```
<ng-container cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane">
  <mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve what you want by adding the below onMoved() to the cdkDrag element:

1. add the cdkDragMoved

```html
<ng-container cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (cdkDragMoved)="onMoved()">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
                {{ option }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

2. add the below onMove() impl:

```js
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
  
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autocomplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger 
  
onMoved() {
  this.autocomplete.updatePosition();
}
```

You are done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane" [cdkDragDisabled]="lockDragging" >
    <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (focus)="lockDragging = true" (blur)="lockDragging = false">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

```
lockDragging: boolean;
```

This solution was used to lock dragging when focused on. On the event of a blur, the lock is removed, and the user can drag the window then. This prevents the mat-option section from being static while the user is dragging the modal.